# how to hide code tab in team foundation server 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

Is there anyway to hide TFS code tab in web interface, I already deny access to source control, and it is working from inside VS, but not from the TFS web interface, the users still able to download the source code as zip file.

[Code tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vLQp.png)

Answer (score 3):

You can make them ["Stakeholders"](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/connect/work-as-a-stakeholder) which removes their access to code entirely. Or you can remove the "Read" permission for those users. You can adjust security by right clicking on a folder and choosing "Security".

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what I want to do, is to deny access to code tab from web interface, I don't want to add users to stakeholders neither remove the read permission. do you know a way to do this?

Comment: I gave you two options to deny people access to source code. Stakeholder removes the tab entirely.